# Umbraco losing admin nodes

Tags: umbraco

After a publish up to a remote server the Umbraco admin section on the remote server is not showing any nodes.  The pages and images and everything serve correctly, but in the Umbraco admin section there is nothing below the top level nodes in each section and I can't right click and choose 'republish entire site'.

I've connected my localhost version to the same database and there I can see the node structures (but republishing made no difference) and I could see the node structures on the remote server before the latest push which did not include any .config changes.

Does anyone have a script that will re-create the node structure?

**EDIT**

I've seen a number of links on the Umbraco site like Unable to publish content into umbraco.config but none of it helped - including some permissions advice like @Niks.

I do have a workaround which is to stop and restart the server - which re-populated the nodes without any side-effects - but obviously this is inappropriate in a live environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this before manifesting as a caching problem. Firstly you should make Umbraco refresh its node cache. To do this hit the URL -

```
http://example.com/umbraco/dialogs/republish.aspx?xml=true
```

replacing example.com with your own host. Next, recycle the App Pool on the Umbraco server.  Finally, clear your browsers local cache and restart it.

You may also be able to avoid this happening in the first place by completely stopping the Umbraco site you are deploying in IIS, copying up your files and then restarting.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you may have permission issues. If you're on IIS6/7 make sure to add NETWORK SERVICE read/write/modify on the necessary folders:

/App_Data
/config
/css
/scripts
/masterpages
/data
/umbraco
/umbraco_client

If on a lower version of IIS make sure to add ASP.NET with the same permissions. Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Good ideas, may well solve the problem on another occasion.