# Public site vs administration site "out-of-sync"

Tags: asp.net, umbraco6

I am a newbie using Umbraco for the first time. I keep having a strange issue. I made some changes yesterday in my admin section. Today I do not see these changes in my admin section but when I launch the website, I can see these changes. This has happened a couple of times before also eg when I installed uBlogsy etc. Do we have best practices that I need to be aware of(eg: delete the cache files before I use the application every day etc)?

**Umbraco Version:** the latest in version 6.
**Asp.net version:** 4.5 
**Windows and iis version:** Windows 7, IIS Express

Thanks,

Comment: Check the network profile(from your browser) to see what actual nodes the admin panel is retrieving from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, the admin panel loads content from the node cache. So, the problem could be with the node cache or with the permissions.

There is a [SO item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850902/umbraco-losing-admin-nodes) which details how to clear the node cache, see if this can work for you.

As an alternative, please check the network profile (from your browser) to see what actual noes, the admin panel is retrieving from the server (database) calls.

Comment: The SO Item helped a lot. Every time before I start working, I refresh Umbraco's node cache and then delete the browsers local cache and restart it.